# How to stop fmincon after running an elapsed time of T sec?

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am running `fmincon` for a gird. For some points in the grid there is no solution, `exit flag=-2`, and it takes half an hour sometimes to return the flag and start the next point in the grid. However, for the other points the answer is revealed in less than a min. 
  So I thought one possible solution to reduce the unnecessary running time is to define a stop criteria based on elapsed time for each point in the grid. In other words, How to stop `fmincon` after running  an elapsed time of `T sec`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [output function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/output-functions.html):

```
tic
fmincon(.....,optimset('OutputFcn',@outfun,'MaxFunEval',20000))
```

outfun.m :

```
function stop = outfun(x,optimValues,state)
stop = toc>T;
```